# Readfile does not download but displaying characters - Zend REST

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, readfile

I've created a getAction which is downloading a zip archive depending of the parameter ( filename, date ), the action is working perfectly, when I ping the URL, the zip is downloaded.

NOTE: when I add ob_start the server give me a 500 error

getAction:

```
public function getAction()
{
    $fileName = $this->_getParam('fileName');
    $mounth = $this->_getParam('mounth');
    $year = $this->_getParam('year');
    $typDepot = $this->_getParam('typDepot');
    
    $localDir = APPLICATION_DATA.'\viapost\\'.$typDepot.'\Archives\Declaration\\'.$year.'\\'.$mounth;
    $localDir = str_replace("\\", "/", $localDir);
    

    if (file_exists($localDir.'/'.$fileName)) {
    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip, application/download, application/force-download')
            ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"')
            ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
            ->setHeader('Expires', 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT')
            ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
            ->setHeader('Pragma', 'private  ')
            ->setHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
            ->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($localDir.'/'.$fileName));

    ob_clean();   
    ob_end_flush();
    
    readfile($localDir.'/'.$fileName);

    $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    exit();
    }
    else{
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('File not found', 404);
    }
}
```

The other server has to ping the url to download the zip file from this server, the problem is that the zip file is not downloading but a string with weird characters is displaying.

The function to call the getAction :

```
public function totofunction(){
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    // Récupération du paramètre de recherche.
    //$aRequestParams = $this->_getAllParams();

    $errors = array();  
    //$hostnameViapost = Zend_Registry::get('domainPecWs');
    
    try {
        $client = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://ebordereaurec.viapost-services.intra');
    
        // Set headers
        $client->setHeaders(array(
        'Accept-encoding' => 'gzip,deflate',
        'X-Powered-By' => 'Zend Framework',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/zip;',
        'Accept' => 'application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip',
        'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive'
        ));
        // Adding several parameters with one call
        $get_datas = array(
            'fileName'   => '2019-02-18-202.zip',//$aRequestParams['nomFichier'],
            'typDepot'   => 'DRP',//$aRequestParams['typDepot'],
            'year'       => '2020',//$aRequestParams['year'],
            'mounth'     => '06'//$aRequestParams['mounth']
        );
    
        $result = ($client->restGet('/viapost/DownloadCreation/',$get_datas)); 
        
    } catch(Zend_Rest_Client_Exception $e) {
        // catch Rest Client Exception
        $errors[] = '[' . $e->getCode() . ']:' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // catch general exception if any occurs
        // like DB
        $errors[] = '[' . $e->getCode() . ']:' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($result->isError()) {
      echo "Les infos Serveur sont : "
         . $result->getStatus()
         . " " . $result->getMessage()
         . "\n";
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    return $result;
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

The things that I get :
[image: The result and the readfile displaying]

I've tried everything that I found on internet about folder downloading with getAction and Zend REST but it still display the weird string. So if someone has an ideas that would be great.

Comment: _“the problem is that the zip file is not downloading but a string with weird characteres is displaying”_ - those “weird characters” _are_ the binary content of your ZIP file. You just _output_ the result of your request to the screen, instead of actually _storing_ the response body contents into a file.

Comment: Alright, thank you, i'll try to put this content into a file

Answer (score 0):

```
setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip, application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, multipart/x-zip, application/download, application/force-download')
```

This line in goAction looks weired, I think it leads the browser can't determine the exact content type. Then the browser treat the contents as text/html.

Try this:

```
setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
```

Comment: Tried it, it gave me the same think :/

Comment: These **weird characters** was binary data belongs to the zip file. When you access the URL served by goAction in a browser, it will be downloaded as a ZIP file. But if you access the URL from another PHP script, and users access the URL served by the second PHP script, you should send the content type header again in the second PHP script.